# ISSUE: can't access Json data inside the html template, AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am using combination of AngularJS 1.5.x and Angular Material. I have data stored in ../JSON/data.json, I am testing the whole thing in python3 localhost server.

The data is retrieved correctly and shows up in the Google Chrome Consoler

I have an HTML template

```
<md-tab label="one" class="material-tab">
  <md-content class="md-padding" layout="column" layout-align="center center">
    <md-card class="card-tab card-bg">
      <md-card-title>
        <md-card-title-text>
          <span class="md-headline"> {{vm.info[0].tab}} Bone Bone</span>
          <span class="md-subhead">Text</span>
        </md-card-title-text>
        <md-card-title-media>
          <img class="md-media-lg" src="../IMG/favicon.png" />
        </md-card-title-media>
      </md-card-title>
      <md-card-actions>
        <md-button class="md-raised md-primary">See More</md-button>
        <md-button class="md-raised md-warn">Full List</md-button>
        <md-button class="md-raised md-primary button-right">Email</md-button>
      </md-card-actions>
    </md-card>
  </md-content>
</md-tab>
```

I have a js directive and controller attached to it

```
(function() {
  angular
    .module('webApp')
    .controller('showcaseController', showcaseController)
    .directive('boneShowcaseTab', boneShowcaseTab);

  showcaseController.$inject = ['$http'];

  function showcaseController($http) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.info = [];

    $http.get('../JSON/data.json').success(function(response) {
      console.log("Loaded data.json");
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response));       // TODO remove

      vm.info = response.data.information;
    });
  };

  function boneShowcaseTab($http) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: '../TEMPLATES/tabs.html',
      controller: 'showcaseController',
      controllerAs: 'tabs'
    };
  };
})();
```

However when I try to access the json data {{vm.info[0].tab}} nothing is being displayed.

More importantly, when I try to attach **ng-repeat** to the **md-tab** the whole thing disappears. Here is how I reference the directive

```
  <md-tabs flex md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom md-stretch-tabs="always"> <bone-showcase-tab></bone-showcase-tab>                                   <!-- CUSTOM TABS -->
  </md-tabs>
```

So... question is... where did I done goofed?

P.S. I am still a newbie in Angular, so pardon any "bad code".

P.P.S. the ng-repeat logic is not here yet, as I have trouble accessing JSON data :)

P.P.P.S Can't access any variable. Even if I create a test `vm.test = "test"` I can't access it in any way.

Comment: use 'then' instead of 'success' and also put an [error callback](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), and log response object properties for debugging purposes.

Comment: I know that JSON data is received correctly since calling       console.log(vm.info[0].tab) outputs value "bones" as it should. However, calling same thing in HTML template, doesn't show anything.

Comment: P.S. forgot to mention, same result with calling .then

Comment: `vm.info[0].tab` is not bound to any scope, nor vm is a reference to an aliased controller.

Comment: Ok, for dummies then, how do you bind variable to a scope? I used same logic as I did with arrays  var data = this;

    data.social = [{
      name: 'Phone',
      icon: '../IMG/phone-bottom.png',
      action: '839129832'
    }, {
      name: 'Email',
      icon: '../IMG/email-bottom.png',
      action: 'email'
    }];

Comment: since you don't use an isolated scope, you are using the inherited scope, and `controllerAs` is set to tabs. So try: `tabs.info[0].tab`

Comment: @LuisMasuelli YOU ARE A BOSS! That worked. I knew it was simple as hell, my god I feel stupid. I will copy paste your response, give credits and mark it as a valid answer.

Comment: I am writing the answer

Comment: Detailed answer written

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Suggestion: please understand what is a $scope and how values are watched and rendered before messing with directives*.

When creating a directive as you did, your directive is defined as follows:

```
function boneShowcaseTab($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '../TEMPLATES/tabs.html',
        controller: 'showcaseController',
        controllerAs: 'tabs'
    };
};
```

When using this directive (as you correctly did), you will use the **same scope** from the parent (since you are not creating a new scope for the directive; that's why I encourage you to read carefully about scope, parenting, and isolation before messing more with this). Additionally, in the scope (it will work being the scope you are using, or using an isolated one), you created a new variable `tabs` as an alias of the current controller (that is not required but may be a good practice). So, in your rendered html (in the directive template) you will have access to:

```
{{ tabs.something }}
```

And will access `something` member if assigned to the controller.

In the controller code, `vm` is a reference to `this`, and `this` will be aliased as `tabs`, so by transitivity... `vm` in the code will be aliased as `tabs` in the template's html content. So what you're looking for is...

```
{{ tabs.info[0].tab }}
```